# Difference between `\tkzDefShiftPoint` and `\tkzDefShiftPointCoord` in `tkz-euclide`

Tags: tkz-euclide

So I was reading through the `tkz-euclide` documentation and I saw two different commands being used in a similar manner on examples 4.2.2 and 4.2.3.

- `\tkzDefShiftPoint`
- `\tkzDefShiftPointCoord`

Both commands seem to take the same types of arguments and their difference(s) don't seem to be explained in the doc.

I copied the code for the second and I switched the commands around, looking for any output differences.

```
% Original code from doc.
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(30:3){B}
    \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[B](10:2){C}
    \tkzDefShiftPointCoord[A](10:2){D}
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,...,D)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,...,D)
\end{tikzpicture}

% Edited code with \tkzDefShiftPoint used instead.
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(30:3){B}
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](10:2){C}
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](10:2){D}
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,...,D)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,...,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the output for both `tikzpicture`s are pretty much the same.

May I know what the differences between both commands are?

Comment: They are not called `\tkzShiftPoint` and `\tkzShiftPointCoord` but `\tkzDefShiftPoint` and `\tkzDefShiftPointCoord`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a terrible typo. I should fix that. Thanks @AndréC

Comment: Their definitions are a little bit different (see the file `tkz-pbj-points.tex`, lines 215-230: https://github.com/tkz-sty/tkz-base/blob/master/latex/tkz-obj-points.tex#L215). I don't know what kind of differences there are in practical use though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small difference. With `tkzDefShiftPointCoord` you can use coordinates it's impossible with `tkzDefShiftPoint`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=15]
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
\tkzDefShiftPointCoord[2,3](15:5){B}
\tkzDefShiftPointCoord[2,3](-15:5){C}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(B,C)
\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a very subtle difference that I think would be very hard for new users like me to spot. How interesting!

Comment: @Kookie `\tkzDefShiftPoint` is enough and I think it's better to avoid  the coordinates.

Comment: I don't see the need of `tkzDefShiftPoint`, as with `tkzDefShiftPointCoord`you can refer to raw coordinates `\tkzDefShiftPointCoord[2,3](20:5){B}` or named points `\tkzDefShiftPointCoord[A](-30:5){C}`